# DropDownListFor not directly connected to model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having difficulties using the DropDownListFor helper in a form I want to use for login (security is not the matter here).
I would like, instead of asking for the user to type its username, to let him select it from a dropdown list.

But I can't manage to make ASP.NET automatically set the EmpName propoerty of my model to the selected value in the dropdown list.

This is what I've done tried:

The following method displays the login page

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
   // Retrieving all users from DB
   using (var db = new BidManagementContext())
   {
       var users = from u in db.LOGIN
                   select u.EmpName;

       ViewBag.AllUsers = new SelectList(users.ToList());
       return View();
   }
}
```

And these are some lines from the view:

```
<div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmpName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
   <div class="col-md-10">
       @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EmpName, ViewBag.AllUsers as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
   </div>
</div>
```

With how I did things, I have an error when ASP.NET tries to bind the dropdown selected value to the model:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'EmpName'.

I'm not sure what to do here :-/

Comment: It means that `ViewBag.AllUsers` is null. Possibly your returning the view after a submit but not reassigning the `SelectList`

Comment: Did you define a model type for the view?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Oh, it was that simple... I feel a bit stupid :-/
Would you answer the post outside of a comment so that I can upvote and mark your answer as a solution?

Comment: I think you should build a datatype (class) for the elements in the dropdown, and the class must have a field named EmpName.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message means that the value of `ViewBag.AllUsers` is null. This is possibly because your returning the view after a submit but not reassigning the `SelectList`. I recommend refactoring the code for populating `SelectLists` to a private method that can be called in both the GET and POST methods if your return the view.

**Edit** (example added)

```
HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
  YourViewModel model = new YourViewModel();
  ConfigureViewModel(model);
  return View(model);
}

[HtppPost]
public ActionResult Index(YourViewModel model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    ConfigureViewModel(model);
    return View(model);
  }
  // Save and redirect
}

private void ConfigureViewModel(YourViewModel model)
{
  using (var db = new BidManagementContext())
  {
    var users = from u in db.LOGIN select u.EmpName;
    ViewBag.AllUsers = new SelectList(users.ToList());
    // or better, model.AllUsers = new SelectList(users.ToList());
  }
  // any other common operations
}
```